# Ruby On Rails Saving to Database Multiple Tables

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm new to Ruby on Rails and trying to learn it by doing one simple application. What i'm trying to do is to save the details to different tables in a DB using nested attributes. Im getting an unpermited parameters :locations error in my terminal.

here are my files..

State.rb

```
class State < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :locations
end
```

City.rb

```
class City < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :locations
end
```

Location.rb

```
class Location < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :user
    belongs_to :state
    belongs_to :city
end
```

User.rb

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :locations
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :locations
end
```

User Controller.rb

```
class UserController < ApplicationController
  def new
  end
  def create
    p "======================="
    p params
    p "======================="
    p user_params
    p "-----------------------"
    @user = User.new(user_params)
    @user.save
    redirect_to @user
  end

  def update_city_select
    @cities = City.where(state_id: params[:state_id]).order(:name) unless params[:state_id].blank?
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { render layout: false }
      format.js
    end
  end
  def show
    # @user = User.find(params[:id])
    # @location = Location.find(params[:id])
  end
  private
    def user_params
        params.require(:user).permit(:id,:firstname, :lastname,
            :locations_attributes=>[:id,:user_id,:state_id,:city_id]
            )
    end
end
```

new.html.erb

```
<html>
    <head></head>
    <body>

        <%= form_for :user, url: users_path do |j| %>
            <div id="first_name">
                <label>First Name</label>
                <div>
                    <%= j.text_field :firstname %>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div id="last_name">
                <label>Last Name</label>
                <div>
                    <%= j.text_field :lastname %>
                </div>
            </div>
            <%= j.fields_for :locations do |jl| %>
                <%= render 'location_fields', :j => jl %>
            <% end %>
            <div>
                <div id="submit">
                    <%= j.submit %>             
                </div>
            </div>  
        <%end%>

        <script type="text/javascript">
            $("#state_name").change(function() {
                var state = $('#state_name :selected').val();
                $.ajax({
                    url: '/student_profile/update_city_select',
                    type: 'GET',
                    data: {
                    state_id: state
                    },
                success: function(response) {
                    $('#city_name').html(response);                 
                    }
                });
            });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

and _location_fields.html.erb

```
<div id="state_name">
    <label>Location[State]</label>
    <div>                   
        <%= j.select :state_id, State.all.map{|j| [j[:name], j[:id]]} %>
    </div>
</div>
<div>
    <label>City</label>
    <div id="city_name">
        <%= j.select :city_id, {} ,{} %>
    </div>
</div>
```

I have this 4 fields in my page. First Name and Last Name gets saved to the User table. What im trying to achieve is that i want to save the state_id and city_id to locations table. State and City tables have a set of Variables. State anD City are dropdown list. Upon selecting one state corresponding cities will be loaded to the Cities Dropdown.

Here is the output from terminal..

```
"======================="
{"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"7zmznmSLQ+D/089mZLjrT0H784lsX1ERilyvP68jG4I=", "user"=>{"firstname"=>"Nidhin", "lastname"=>"Besole", "locations"=>{"state_id"=>"3"}}, "city_id"=>"28516", "commit"=>"Save User", "controller"=>"user", "action"=>"create"}
"======================="
Unpermitted parameters: locations
{"firstname"=>"Nidhin", "lastname"=>"Besole"}
"-----------------------"
Unpermitted parameters: locations
```

THanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use an User instance (@user) to build the form. You are using :user symbol now. Your building form knows nothing about User model and passes locations parameters as **locations** instead of **locations_attributes**.

User Controller.rb

```
class UserController < ApplicationController
  def new
    @user = User.new
  end
  ...
end
```

new.html.erb

```
<html>
    <head></head>
    <body>

        <%= form_for @user do |j| %>
        ...
```

**Solution 2:**

You can just pass **:locations_attributes** symbol to fields_for helper instead of **:locations** symbol:

```
<%= j.fields_for :locations_attributes do |jl| %>
```